# How do I create new instances of an object in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, object, sdk, clone

I'm working on a concept that will have objects falling from the top of the screen. For this example lets say, 4 objects: red square, blue square, green square, yellow square.

I have all of these objects placed in the interface builder and connected with the names given in the .h files: IBObject UIImageView *greenSquare; for example.

I able to interact with the "greenSquare" fine and have it fall from the top of the view to the bottom and disappear off the view. Right now I want to be able to recreate the "greenRectangle" and have it fall again. I can't just reset that one instance since at any given point 1 or more of the same object would be falling.

The end result would be x number of the squares of any of the colors would be showing and falling.

I'm sure my workflow for this would be:

- Set time to pick square
- position square
- show square
- drop square at x rate

Any push in the right direction would be great. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is what I did:

in my .h file I created the object instances:

```
UIImageView *yellowImage;
UIImageView *greenImage;
UIImageView *orangeImage;
UIImageView *redImage;

UIImage *yellow;
UIImage *green;
UIImage *orange;
UIImage *red;
```

I then set the images:

```
green = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greenball.png"];
yellow = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yellowball.png"];
orange = [UIImage imageNamed:@"orangeBall.png"];
red = [UIImage imageNamed:@"redball.png"];
```

I called a method and set a timer:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(0.5) target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

finally, inside the onTimer I create a random number that chooses a ball and creates it like this:

```
greenImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:green];
greenImage.frame = CGRectMake(startX,0,43,43);
[self.view insertSubview:greenImage belowSubview:bottomBar];
```

Answer (score 2):

why do you use InterfaceBuilder for this - switch to a "code only" implementation and you should be just fine.

1) create image

```
UIImage *green = [UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"];
UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:green];
[view addSubview:img];
```

2) position it

```
img.center = CGPointMake(<RANDOM NUMBER>, -30);
```

3) start animation
4) when it hits the bottom, remove it

```
[img removeFromSuperview];
```

5) add this img to the top again ...

if you want to have multiple of these green img you can create more than one at a time. if just one is enough you could reuse the `img` every time the animation reached the bottom.

***edit***

if you want to create multiple `UIImageView`s from one `UIImage` do it like this:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"green"];

UIImageView *imgView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
imgView1.center = CGPointMake(100, 100);
[self.view addSubview:imgView1];

UIImageView *imgView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
imgView2.center = CGPointMake(100, 500);
[self.view addSubview:imgView2];
```

Comment: There will be times where, say, a green will be called more than once within less than a second of each other. In that instance I would have two greens on the screen at the same time and falling right after they show.

Comment: that shouldn't be a problem - just use the same PNG to create two instances.

Comment: view.addSubview(img) gave me an error. However, [self.view addSubview:img] works perfect. So, in instance [self.view addSubview:img] twice would give me two of the greenballs. How would set I two different CGPointMake positions. I assume I set, for example, UIImageView *img2 = img; [self.view addSubview:img2] ?

Comment: i edited the answer to include an example of how to create multiple imageviews from one image.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should think about to set the rectangles y position back to the top of screen just when it disappears at the bottom. So you don´t have to recreate it and can reuse it. Dan

Comment: That would work if I only want one to show on the screen. However, my application may hav 0->x instances of the object.